# Success function bound to x-editable not executing with correct parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures, x-editable

I call the following function several times after my page is loaded.  The intent is to incrementally load a lot of similarly-formatted companies from the server.  For each company I would like to find all the `x-editable` elements and bind a `success` handler function.  The success handler in each case should call a refresh function passing in the name and id of this particular company.

This all more or less works -- the companies load incrementally, I'm able to find the matching `x-editable`s and bind my `success` function to them.

The problem is that when the page is fully loaded and I use an `x-editable` to edit some data the `refreshCompany()` function is executed but with the wrong `company_name` and `company_guid`.  The name and id that appear in the `Refresh. . .` console message are the same for all companies in a container, and always the *last* one from company list, not the one that appeared in the `Load. . .` console message.

I believe one of two things may be happening:

- The `company_name` and `company_guid` values are remaining bound to the *current* (ish) values in the outer scope due to closure rules I do not fully understand.

  - My `.find('.editable')` search is operating not on my newly created company-specific object but rather on the container holding all the companies (my original implementation used `.append()` instead of `.appendTo()` and definitely suffered from this problem).

How can I modify the following code such that `refreshCompany()` will be executed using the name and id values at the time the function is bound?

```
 function loadCompanies(company_list, container_name, link_container_name) {

    var searchTerm = '#' + container_name;

    for (company of company_list)
    {

        var company_name = company.name;
        var company_guid = company.id;
        console.log('Load ' + company_name + ' ' + company_guid);

        $.ajax(
            {
                url : '${fund.name}/' + encodeURIComponent( company_name ),
                type : 'GET'
            }
        ).done (
            function (company_html) {
                var newElement = $(company_html).appendTo('#' + container_name);
                newElement.find('.editable').editable(
                    {
                        success : function (response, newValue) {
                            console.log('Refresh ' + company_name + ' ' + company_guid)
                            refreshCompany(company_name, company_guid);
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps but it seems the problem is that by the time you get a response from the asynchronous GET request you have already looped through 
all of the companies in the list, so when the success method runs, 
company_name and company_guid are bound the last company in the list.

I think you should be able to solve this problem with a closure.  Perhaps something like defining a function outside loadCompanies like :

```js
function refreshClosure(companyName, companyGuid) {
 return function () {
  console.log('Refresh ' + companyName + ' ' + companyGuid)
  refreshCompany(companyName, companyGuid);
 }
}
```

...and using it in your code like this:

```js
function loadCompanies(company_list, container_name, link_container_name) {

    var searchTerm = '#' + container_name;

    for (var company in company_list)
    {

        var company_name = company.name;
        var company_guid = company.id;
      
        // Enclose the current value of company_name and company_guid
        var refreshCurrent = refreshClosure(company_name, company_guid);
        
      console.log('Load ' + company_name + ' ' + company_guid);

        $.ajax(
            {
                url : '${fund.name}/' + encodeURIComponent( company_name ),
                type : 'GET'
            }
        ).done (
            function (company_html) {
                var newElement = $(company_html).appendTo('#' + container_name);
                newElement.find('.editable').editable(
                    {
                        success : function (response, newValue) {
                        // Invoke the function returned from the closure
                            refreshCurrent();
                        }
                    }
                );
            }
        );

    }
}
```

I also changed the for statement in case that was part of the problem.  Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: Using this solution I saw a similar problem; the success function was still using company names that were bound at the end of the process (although, since the `refreshCurrent()` closure was outside the scope of `loadCompanies()` I was now seeing the last company from *any* call to `loadCompanies()`).  Moving the `var refreshCurrent = refreshClosure(company_name, company_guid);` inside the scope of the `done()` function was not enough to avoid that problem, but doing that *combined with* getting locally-scoped `cn` and `id` variables (from the `companyHtml`) did the trick.